# Update NSUserDefaults data in one ViewController changed in other ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I got two viewcontroller: MainController and OptionsController. 
OptionsController it can be reached through a button from MainController.
In OptionsController is there some values that I can save with NSUserDefaults. These values are needed in MainController.
If I change these values in OptionsController when I come back to MainController they don’t change, but if I launch MainController again, these values was changed correctly.
It seems that when MainController becomes active again, after leaving OptionsController, viewDidLoad is no longer raised.
How can I update the data in MainController, please?

Comment: The answer given provides the answer you need. Just search how to use NSNotification. You should vote up the answer if it is helpful. That will encourage others to help you in the future.

Comment: You're right, and both the answers gave me some good ideas, but unfortunatly I can't vote yet, 'cause my reputation points are less than 15.

Comment: OK - I just put you over the limit. Vote away. BTW accepting an answer that is most helpful will give you two extra points so hit the green check mark if one of the answers is very useful.Search SO for How to use NSNotifications and you're on your way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As rounak says, `viewDidLoad` is only called once in the life of a view controller. If you have code you want executed every time a view controller is shown, put it in `viewWillAppear`.

`NSUserDefaults`is a fairly heavyweight way to pass info between in-memory objects (it writes to disk). If you don't need persistence between runs, one of the other options he suggested would be better. I'd suggest the delegate pattern or a completion block.

Comment: I need persistence data too. I will look for yours indications. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

viewDidLoad is called only once for a view controller. You can use NSNotification, KVO, blocks or something like a delegate pattern to get a callback in your MainController whenever the value changes inside the OptionsController.

You can otherwise write code in viewWillAppear which gets called each time you pop the options controller.